# How to change 2 properties in Xcode 4?

Tags: text-editor, xcode

I would like to do 2 things in the xCode:

1. enabling spelling correction in the comments.
2. unrolling the lines of code/comment, I mean like when I have a long line of code xCode won't break it to 3-4 lines and it all be in one long line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one Press,

#### A quick way :

<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>:</kbd>

#### A permanent way

```
Click on Edit>Format>Spelling and Grammar>and then select "Check spelling while typing"
```

---

For the second question,

```
Goto Xcode>Preferences>Text Editing>Indentetion and then select "Wrap lines to editor width".
```

As shown in this picture,

[image]